# C# WinForms. Некорректная запись image в файл. System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, winforms, save

Пишу программу, что открывает картинки через **MDI WinForms**.
Пытаясь сохранить картинку, я натыкаюсь на ошибку: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: "A generic error occurred in GDI+.".`

Иллюстрация ошибки:
[image: Вот так выглядит ошибка.]

Пытаясь её поправить, я проверил, что при выполнении функции `File.Exists(path)`, *директория существует, разрешения даны*.
Так же, при тестировании мною было проверено, что в `ImageBuffer` активной формы имеется картинка и `ImagePath`.
Так же корректно обрабатывается `ImageFormat`. Изначально я пытался так же сохранять просто `Image`, но по совету из другой статьи я инициализирую `Bitmap`, и это всё равно не работает.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!
Приведу пример функции отрисовки картинки:

```
public partial class FormChild : Form
    {
        public Image ImageBuffer { get; private set; }
        public ImageFormat ImageFormat { get; private set; }
        
        public string ImagePath { get; private set; }

        private FormGeneral _parent { get; set; }
        private Graphics _grfx { get; set; }
        private Rectangle _rect{ get; set; }

        public FormChild(FormGeneral parent, string caption)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Присваиваем публичным свойствам значения
            ImageBuffer = null;
            ImagePath = string.Empty;

            // Присваиваем приватным свойствам значения
            _parent = parent;
            _grfx = null;
            _rect = ClientRectangle;
            _defaultColor = Color.White;

            // Подписываем события
            this.Paint += FormChild_Paint;
            this.Resize += FormChild_Resize;

            // Присваивание контейнеру родителя данной формы
            this.MdiParent = parent;

            // Задание заголовка
            this.Text = caption;
        }
        public void FormChild_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ImageBuffer == null)
                return;

            _grfx = e.Graphics;

            _grfx.DrawImage(ImageBuffer, 0, 0, _rect.Width, _rect.Height);

            _grfx.Dispose();
        }
        public void UploadImageToBuffer()
        {
            if (_parent.ImageBuffer == null || _parent.ImagePath == string.Empty)
                return;

            ImageBuffer = _parent.ImageBuffer;
            ImagePath = _parent.ImagePath;
            ImageFormat = GetImageFormat();
        }
        public ImageFormat GetImageFormat() {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(ImagePath).ToLower();

            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".bmp":
                    return ImageFormat.Bmp;
                case ".gif":
                    return ImageFormat.Gif;
                case ".png":
                    return ImageFormat.Png;
                case ".tiff":
                    return ImageFormat.Tiff;
                case ".jpeg":
                    return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                case ".jpg":
                    return ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        private void FormChild_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            Invalidate();//перерисовать

    }
```

Пример функции сохранения(класс `FormGeneral`):

```
private void SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FormChild activeChildForm = (FormChild)this.ActiveMdiChild) { 
                if (activeChildForm != null)
                {
                    DialogResult dialogResult =
                         MessageBox.Show("Вы хотите сохранить картинку в том же файле?", "Внимание!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        if (activeChildForm.ImageBuffer != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(activeChildForm.ImagePath) && activeChildForm.ImageFormat != null)
                        {
                            Image image = Image.FromFile(activeChildForm.ImagePath);
                            
                            Bitmap images = new Bitmap(image);
                            activeChildForm.ImageBuffer.Save(activeChildForm.ImagePath, activeChildForm.GetImageFormat());
                            
                            activeChildForm.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("ActiveMdiChild == null!");
            }
        }
```

Функция открытия файла(класс `FormGeneral`)

```
private void OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //если результат равен Cancel, то выходим
            if (OpenFileDialogWindow.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;

            // получаем выбранный файл
            ImagePath = OpenFileDialogWindow.FileName;

            try
            {
                ImageBuffer = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find file " + ImagePath +
               "!", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                return;
            }

            // Определение активного дочернего MDI-окна
            FormChild activeChildForm = (FormChild)this.ActiveMdiChild;

            if (activeChildForm == null)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult =
                    MessageBox.Show("Вы хотите создать форму для отображения картинки?", "ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    CreateToolStripMenuItem_Click(null, null);//создает дочернюю форму
            }
            else {
                activeChildForm.UploadImageToBuffer();
                activeChildForm.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageBuffer = Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
```

Это и есть `Bitmap`. Вы можете сделать поле

```
public Bitmap ImageBuffer { get; private set; }
```

И грузить туда вот так

```
ImageBuffer = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(ImagePath);
```

С этой типом разобрались.

Далее `Bitmap` может держать файл открытым после чтения столько, сколько ему захочется до того момента, пока вы его не уничтожите через `.Dispose()`.

**Объехать можно так**

```
using (var bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(ImagePath))
{
    ImageBuffer = new Bitmap(bmp);
}
```

Здесь файл будет гарантированно закрыт сразу же после чтения. Я не знаю, почему `FromFile` оставляет файл открытым.

Далее, вы определяете формат файла по расширению, не надо так делать. Определяйте формат файла по формату данных

```
public ImageFormat GetImageFormat()
{
    return ImageBuffer.RawFormat;
}
```

Вот и вся магия.

---

А вот расширение можно определять в обратную сторону.

Например так

```
public static string GetExtension(ImageFormat format)
{
    if (format == ImageFormat.Icon)
        return ".ico";
    if (format == ImageFormat.MemoryBmp)
        return ".bmp";
    return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FormatID == format.Guid)?
        .FilenameExtension
        .Split(';')[0]
        .TrimStart('*')
        .ToLower() ?? $".{format.ToString().ToLower()}";
}
```

Страшновато, но зато поддерживает все известные `ImageFormat`

```
ImageFormat[] formats = new[]
{
    ImageFormat.Bmp, ImageFormat.Emf, ImageFormat.Exif, ImageFormat.Gif,
    ImageFormat.Icon, ImageFormat.Jpeg, ImageFormat.MemoryBmp, ImageFormat.Png,
    ImageFormat.Tiff, ImageFormat.Wmf
};

foreach (var format in formats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetExtension(format));
}
```

Даст вывод

```
.bmp
.emf
.exif
.gif
.ico
.jpg
.bmp
.png
.tif
.wmf
```

Но вам по сути это даже не понадобится, потому что сама картинка `ImageBuffer` содержит в себе целевой формат.

---

Теперь как сохранить, убрал все лишнее.

```
private void SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ActiveMdiChild is null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ActiveMdiChild == null!");
        return; 
    }
    if (MessageBox.Show("Вы хотите сохранить картинку в том же файле?", "Внимание!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        try
        {
            FormChild activeChildForm = (FormChild)this.ActiveMdiChild;
            if (activeChildForm.ImageBuffer is null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Нечего сохранять, изображение не загружено");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activeChildForm.ImagePath))
                throw new ArgumentException("Не задан путь сохранения");

            activeChildForm.ImageBuffer.Save(activeChildForm.ImagePath, activeChildForm.ImageBuffer.ImageFormat);
            activeChildForm.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

`using` не нужен, так как вы все равно ее закрываете через `Close()`

Comment: ```public ImageFormat GetImageFormat()
{
    return ImageBuffer.ImageFormat;
}``` . К сожалению, я нашел лишь свойство ```RawFormat```, а такого как вы указали, не существует. А по поводу ```GetExtension```, может где-то пригодится) Но есть одна проблемка: ошибка всё еще со мной. Всё та же)

Comment: @СкептическийХомяк да, все верно, я опечатался, `RawFormat`. А про ошибку - не может быть, либо есть еще код, с которым проблемы.

Comment: Ни в каких посторонних приложениях я файлы не открываю - в следствии - я это 100% в этом проекте что-то мешает. Я вам могу скинуть ссылку на репозиторий, если вам так удобнее будет посмотреть поближе. Он у меня приватный

Comment: @СкептическийХомяк GDI+ не может записть файл, это факт. Либо файл занят, либо нет прав доступа. Если вы поменяете путь на другой, все запишется. В репозиторий смотреть не буду, нет сейчас возможности этим заниматься. Проверяйте, где вы используйтее файл, закрываете ли его при каждом открытии, т. д. Наверняка где-то еще `FromFile` затерялся.

Comment: Это прозвучит смешно, но факту вся программа уже у вас.. Кроме нескольких строк - конструктора. Так же, это единственное место, где есть FromFile. Файл удалил перед сохранением - ошибка та же. Так то она больше нигде и не используется...

Comment: @СкептическийХомяк то есть файла вообще не стало, но исключение все равно возникает?

Comment: Да. Самое интересное, что когда мы пытались без удаления сохранить файл - он ломался(просто иконка файла сохраняется, а сам файл пустым становиться).

Comment: @СкептическийХомяк нашел проблему, исправил ответ, там где _Объехать можно так_ вставил новый код. Оказывается, стрим нельзя закрывать, если хочется потом это сохранить. Вообще странная магия, ну да ладно. Удалять файл не нужно, само перезаписывается нормально.

Comment: Боже, вы волшебник, я люблю вас, спасибо