Ошибка System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: "A generic error occurred in GDI+." после того, как добавил 1 метод в программу
В моей программе достаточно много раз нужно сохранять скриншоты и затем обрабатывать их. Раньше ошибок не появлялось и работало исправно часами. Но теперь, когда я добавил следующий метод:
 private async Task CheckTable()
 {
     Image image = CaptureScreen(757, 476, 0, 0, size3);

     image.Save(@"C:\ImageTests\screeeen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);


     using (Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(@"C:\langs", "rus", OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined))
     {
         tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\ImageTests\screeeen.jpg"));
         tesseract.Recognize();
         if (tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("\r\n", "").Contains("Вы успешно") || tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("\r\n", "").Contains("не доступен"))
         {
             return;
         }
         else
         {
            await Task.Delay(50);
            await  CheckTable();
         }
     }
 }

и использовал в коде его так:
var tableCheck = CheckTable();
await tableCheck;
tableCheck.Dispose();

то в случайном фрагменте кода, где я тоже выполнял сохранение фотографий, начала спустя некоторое количество времени вылезать ошибка:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Как это можно исправить?

Вот тут почитайте, может окажется полезным: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1053738/c-the-dreaded-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-exce   И вот тут еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515657/c-winforms-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-image-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-system-runtime-interopservices-ex

@AlexanderSt я смотрел эту информацию, но мне показалось странным, что до того как добавил метод все работало нормально и поэтому боюсь, не навредит ли следование данным советам производительности программы.  Мне же все-таки нужно не просто убрать ошибку, а  найти причину почему она появляется и может ли снизить скорость выполнения

в тех источниках явно ссылаются на возникновении ошибки при выполнении image.Save(); Предлагаю вам проверить хотя бы 2 условия, которые там упоминаются: существует ли уже файл с таким именем, куда вы пытаетесь сохранять картинку и не превышен ли лимит в 65535 pixels

ну по этим 2 условиям все нормально

Картинку задиспозить забыли, поэтому она файл не отпустила
using (Image image = CaptureScreen(757, 476, 0, 0, size3))
{
    image.Save(@"C:\ImageTests\screeeen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

Вообще у GDI+ есть странности при работе с файлами, но их стоит учитывать.
Что касается tableCheck.Dispose(); - то Task.Dispose() вызывать не нужно.
await CheckTable();

Избавиться от рекурсии можно так, вам кстати и асинхронность в методе не нужна
private bool CheckTable()
{
    using (Image image = CaptureScreen(757, 476, 0, 0, size3))
    {
        image.Save(@"C:\ImageTests\screeeen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    using (Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(@"C:\langs", "rus", OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined))
    {
        tesseract.SetImage(new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\ImageTests\screeeen.jpg"));
        tesseract.Recognize();
        bool result = tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("\r\n", "").Contains("Вы успешно") || tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("\r\n", "").Contains("не доступен");
        return result;
    }
}

А вызывать вот так
while (!CheckTable())
{
    await Task.Delay(50);
}


Кстати, можно вообще без файла обойтись
private bool CheckTable()
{
    using Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(@"C:\langs", "rus", OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined);
    Image<Bgr, byte> image = CaptureScreen(757, 476, 0, 0, size3).ToImage();
    tesseract.SetImage(image);
    tesseract.Recognize();
    string text = tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("\r\n", ""); 
    bool result = text.Contains("Вы успешно") || text.Contains("не доступен");
    return result;
}


Спасибо, надеюсь сработает

ошибка в последнем. " Не удается неявно преобразовать тип System.Drawing.Image в Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr.Byte>"

@user643875 здесь нет нигде неявных преобразований, убедитесь что вы верно скопировали код.
